# Remove selected option from Angular select box in ng-repeat for next index

Tags: html, angularjs, repeat

I am working on drop down in angular js which is already in ng-repat option. 
I want to make it work in a way that when an option is selected in any of repeated select box it should not be available in other repeated select boxes. 
My current code looks like this. :

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="endDate in endDate_counts">
<div class="sch_endDate_opsAmount_cell cell1">
<strong class="nc_Camaignfinance_title">Option</strong>
 <div class="nc_Camaign_costFinance_opsSlct" select-input>
   <div class="nc_Camaign_costFinance_opsSlct_inn">
    <span>{{endDate.select_endDate}}</span>
   <ul>
  <li ng-click="endDate.select_endDate = 'Never'">
        <em>Never</em></li>
    <li ng-click="endDate.select_endDate = 'Impressions'">
        <em>Impressions</em></li>
    <li  ng-click="endDate.select_endDate = 'Budget'">
        <em>Budget</em></li>
    <li  ng-click="endDate.select_endDate = 'Clicks'">
        <em>Clicks</em></li>
    <li  ng-click="endDate.select_endDate = 'Date'">
        <em>Date</em></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

*Note: Please ignore the custom directives or other methods. I am using them myself and aware of them .

Comment: Do you have any working fiddle?

Comment: No sir , but I can share my complete code if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

html:

```
<ul>
<li ng-show="checkExist(key-1,'Never')" ng-click="endDate.select_endDate = 'Never'">
    <em>Never</em></li>
<li ng-show="checkExist(key-1,'Impressions')" ng-click="endDate.select_endDate = 'Impressions'">
    <em>Impressions</em></li>
<li ng-show="checkExist(key-1,'Budget')" ng-click="endDate.select_endDate = 'Budget'">
    <em>Budget</em></li>
<li ng-show="checkExist(key-1,'Clicks')" ng-click="endDate.select_endDate = 'Clicks'">
    <em>Clicks</em></li>
<li ng-show="checkExist(key-1,'Date')" ng-click="endDate.select_endDate = 'Date'">
    <em>Date</em></li>
```

add this function in your js file:

```
$scope.checkExist = function(index,value){
    if(index < 0){
        return true;
    }

    if($scope.endDate_counts[index].select_endDate == value){
        return false;
    }else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: let me implement it , please